# Checkbox Enabling

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, checkbox

For Xamarin Forms:

I am looking to use checkboxes to enable the next set in a series. I have used x:name to set the names of the checkboxes (Fiore, Leichtenauer and Guards). My goal is to set a if statement to change the IsEnabled to false/true in the code behind when the first checkbox is checked. I seem to be getting an error for the IsEnabled, what should I be using instead? Thank you in advance.

```
private void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, CheckedChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Fiore.IsChecked)
        {
            Leichtenauer = IsEnabled(false),
            Guards = IsEnabled(true)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here's the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.visualelement.isenabled?view=xamarin-forms) if you haven't seen it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IsEnabled` is a **property** of the control, so you would set it like

```
    if (Fiore.IsChecked)
    {
        Leichtenauer.IsEnabled = false;
        Guards.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```